# Problems with CORS when testing local

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am having this issue:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://localhost:5001/api/user/authenticate' from origin
> 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

I've been trying several ways to solve for example using the chrome plugin CORS unblock, but, no success so far. Im getting a different error when using the plugin:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://localhost:5001/api/user/authenticate' from origin
> 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have
> HTTP ok status.

In my Startup.CS I have the following:

```
//ConfigureServices
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:5001",  "http://localhost:4200")
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials();
            }));

//Configure
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
app.UseMvc();
```

Frontend:

```
 return this.http.post<ApiResult>(`${environment.apiUrl}/user/authenticate`, { username, password })
```

I am using:

- Dotnet Core 3.1
- Angular 8

Comment: Could you post the whole startup , pls ?

Comment: Please [edit] your code to show what research you've done. This is one of the most common errors asked about on Stack Overflow and you will get downvoted without showing what research you've done and what questions you've already looked at.

Comment: Are you receiving a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header?

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes, I get this as response: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: localhost:4200, but only when I activate the CORS unblock plugin

Comment: Could you please try removing "MyPolicy" policy from ConfigureServices method and directly registering .AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials() methods in Configure method if it works or not?